# List High Priority Processes in listbox

Tags: c#

Exactly what the title says,

I need help figuring out how to list high priority processes in a listbox. I'm able to pull up all the processes in a listbox, but unfiltered.

```
     Process[] allprocs;
    private void GetProccesses()
    {
        allprocs = Process.GetProcesses();
        if(Convert.ToInt32(ProcNumLabel.Text) != allprocs.Length)
        {
            ProcList.Items.Clear();

            for(int i=0; i<allprocs.Length; i++)
            {
                ProcList.Items.Add(allprocs[i].ProcessName);
            }
            ProcNumLabel.Text = allprocs.Length.ToString();
        }
```

I have a label that counts the amount of process in the current list. The high priority list box is my next step I'd like to do.

Added:

```
     for(int i=0; i<allprocs.Length; i++)
            {

              ProcList.Items.Add(allprocs[i].ProcessName);
                if(allprocs[i].PriorityClass == ProcessPriorityClass.High)
                {
                    HiList.Items.Clear();
                    HiList.Items.Add(allprocs[i].ProcessName);
                }
            }
            ProcNumLabel.Text = allprocs.Length.ToString();
```

Solved my issue.

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetAllProcesses();
    }
    private void GetAllProcesses()
    {
        AllProcBox.Items.Clear();
        HiPriBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.BasePriority == 13)
            {
                HiPriBox.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
            if (p.BasePriority < 13)
            {
                AllProcBox.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }

        }
    }
```

get's the job done.

Windows doesn't like "ProcessPriorityClass.High"

Comment: What is your question? If you don't know how to get the priority, then the answer is to use the [`Process.PriorityClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass(v=vs.110).aspx) property: `if (allprocs[i].PriorityClass == PriorityClass.High) { add to list box }`

Comment: This was the general direction I was heading in, just couldn't figure out quite where to put it in the code.

Comment: @Quantic as soon as I added that code, an exemption gets thrown. Access is denied. I tried compiling the running the exe in admin mode, still the same thing more or less.

Comment: Looks like I got the enum name wrong, it's actually [`ProcessPriorityClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processpriorityclass(v=vs.110).aspx), so you probably want `if (allprocs[i].PriorityClass == ProcessPriorityClass.High) { add to list box }` instead

Answer (score 0):

try

```
allprocs = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p=>p.PriorityClass == PriorityClass.High).ToArray();
```

make sure you have `using system.linq`

Comment: Sadly, it didn't take that either. 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnum<Sys.Diag.Process> to 'Sys.Diag.Process'

Comment: Access is denied. Native Error Code 5. Remove anything pertaining to the high priority, Code works.

Comment: if you want further diagnostic help you must post new code with exact details of what error you are getting and where

Comment: Updated it. Here's the exemption:
Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll

Additional information: Access is denied

Comment: There's some redundancy in there, I was just seeing if I could get that exemption not to be thrown.

Comment: more specifically
().Where(p => p.PriorityClass == ProcessPriorityClass.High)
is the problem